# Privilege tracker on user profile activity tab still lists "expandable usercard" as a 1,000+ reputation privilege

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

Recently, the expanded usercard is now offered universally to all users, rather than requiring the *established user* privilege (1,000+ rep on designed sites).

However, the privilege tracker in the user profile still lists it as a privilege that will be gained once I earn 1,000 reputation:

> [image: Next privilege: "See votes, expandable usercard"]

Can this please be fixed?

I suggest changing this to "Established user (see votes)" to better make use of the space and explain what exactly the privilege is about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE** on January 27, 2020

The privilege API is updated [`/2.2/privileges?page=2&pagesize=15&site=meta`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/privileges#page=2&pagesize=15&filter=default&site=meta&run=true)

> [image: API updated]

And the privilege tracker UI is looking now as:

> [image: UI]

It seems the issue has been fixed [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

---

**Initially posted on January 23, 2020**

Currently the Privileges API ([`/2.2/privileges?site=meta`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/privileges#filter=default&site=meta&run=true)) is returning the description as `see votes, expandable usercard`. Updating the API, can solve this issue.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Privileges API]

Comment: You're stealing my thunder 